# DynamicSQL Split function to add criteria from comma delimited string not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to use a split function to add a range of values to a query. I'd also like to 'OR' the values together but first things first. I'm following an example I have found in a much larger query that uses the split function, so I've made a small query to try to figure out how it works. So far though, all I get is the error *"The name 'Select * from Country As sp  WHERE (sp.CountryID in (SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.Split('2,22,', ',')))' is not a valid identifier."* I'm knew to DynamicSQL and I'm not quite sure how this split function is supposed to work.

```
DECLARE @Countries varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @FiltersOn bit;
DECLARE @Country int;
DECLARE @Query  varchar(MAX);

Set @FiltersOn = 0;
Set @Query = 'Select * from Country As sp ';
Set @Countries ='2,22,'



        IF ( @Countries IS NOT NULL )
            BEGIN
                IF ( @FiltersOn = 1 )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Query = @Query + ' AND '
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Query = @Query + ' WHERE '
                        SET @FiltersOn = 1
                    END

                SET @Query = @Query
                    + '(sp.CountryID in (SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.Split('''
                    + @Countries + ''', '','')))'
            END

            EXEC @Query
```

This is the definition of the Country table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [CountryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryLookupID] [int] NOT NULL
```

and this is the split function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String varchar(8000),
    @Delimiter varchar(10)
)
RETURNS @ValueTable table ([Value] varchar(255))

BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextString varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @Pos int
    DECLARE @NextPos int
    DECLARE @DelimiterCheck varchar(1)

    -- initialise
    SET @NextString = ''
    SET @DelimiterCheck = RIGHT(@String, 1)

    -- add trailing delimiter
    IF (@DelimiterCheck <> @Delimiter)
        SET @String = @String + @Delimiter

    -- find position of first delimiter
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)
    SET @NextPos = 1

    -- loop while there is a delimiter in the string
    WHILE (@Pos <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @NextString = SUBSTRING(@String, 1, @Pos - 1)

        INSERT INTO @ValueTable ([Value]) VALUES (@NextString)

        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @Pos + 1, LEN(@String))

        SET @NextPos = @Pos
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: I would suggest tossing that splitter in the trash. Looping to split strings is horrible for performance. My personal favorite is this one. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Several other excellent choices can be found here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: And if you are already using dynamic sql you really don't need to use a splitter to turn a comma delimited string back into a comma delimited string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing `EXEC` statement correctly.

use `EXEC (@Query)` instead of `EXEC @Query`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but something I can recomend reading through as I've seend these solutions create problems in systems before.

I would suggest not using the solution using the WHILE loop. While loops constantly create performance problems as SQL Server doesn't have the same ability to optimize loops as for example C# engines does.

Not sure why you are using dynamic SQL either. If you want to make sure that there is no SQL injection please use sp_executesql instead as it checks for harmful code but i would avoid using dynamic sql except when we don't know the structure of our underlying data (hence need for dynamic sql).

Just wrote a function for doing a string split using cte to keep perfomance up.

```
    CREATE SCHEMA Util;

    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION Util.String_Split (
        @Text varchar(MAX),
        @SplitChar char
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN(
        WITH cte AS
        (
            SELECT
                1 AS [RowNumber],
                X.Text,
                X.RemainingText
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        SUBSTRING(@Text, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @Text) - 1) AS [Text],
                        SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX(';', @Text) + 1, LEN(@Text) - CHARINDEX(';', @Text)) AS [RemainingText]
                ) X
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                cte.RowNumber + 1,
                X.Text,
                X.RemainingText
            FROM
                cte
                CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT
                        SUBSTRING(cte.RemainingText, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(';', cte.RemainingText) - 1, -1), LEN(cte.RemainingText)))  AS [Text],
                        CASE
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(';', cte.RemainingText) = 0 THEN
                                ''
                            ELSE
                                SUBSTRING(cte.RemainingText, CHARINDEX(';', cte.RemainingText) + 1, LEN(cte.RemainingText))
                        END AS [RemainingText]
                ) X
            WHERE
                X.Text  ''
        )
        SELECT
            cte.Text
        FROM
            cte
        WHERE
            cte.Text IS NOT NULL
    );
```

You could then call make your query without the dynamic part using this call:

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Country sp
    WHERE
        @Countries IS NULL
        OR
        sp.CountryId IN (
             SELECT * FROM Util.String_Split(@Countries, ',')
        )
```